# Foreach output into a boolean array

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, boolean

I want to "save" my output from my foreach loop into a boolean array. What would be the easiest way to tackle that?

```
foreach(char est in resultss)
{
    
    int test = est - '0';
    tru = Convert.ToBoolean(test); // A Bool[] instead of Bool
    //  Console.WriteLine(tru);
}
```

I'm working on a binary clock and imp trying to convert a number like 22 into binary (done that) and than into a bool array.

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it.

Comment: `var theArray = resultss.Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x - '0')).ToArray();`

Comment: I will try that out, Thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 List<bool> list = new List<bool>();
 foreach(char est in resultss)
 {
     int test = est - '0';
     tru = Convert.ToBoolean(test);
     list.Add(tru);
 }
```

Comment: That's.. Perfect! Thank u a lot!

Comment: It should be `list.Add(tru)`; C# is case sensitive...

Comment: @uk3ndt please make sure *not to use that* - there is rarely a good reason to use `Convert.` and definitely in this case `Convert.ToBoolean` is wrong method to use. If OP wanted to check `est` being `'0'` or not they should have simply compare it like `list.Add(est != '0')`.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, i changed it like u said :))

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ for this, please add reference to `System.Linq` and do this.

```
var boolArray = resultss.Select(r => Convert.ToBoolean(r - '0')).ToArray();
```

Comment: The second code sample is great, but what does the first code block have to do with this question?

Comment: Actually `Convert.ToBoolean` is awful suggestion too... Either suggest full blown stringly typed approach by converting everything to strings and parsing back on every line or for more practical approach use `r => r != '0'`.

Comment: @RufusL - to introduce LINQ and what it can do for you.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - that's not really the question here.

Comment: I would suggest leaving out the Linq samples, as they are distracting and don't apply to the question. Simply stating that a reference to `System.Linq` is required should be enough.